# Node and handlebars folder structure

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I would like to change my file and folder structure a bit, I tried looking for solutions already online but didn't find anything simple and I have a feeling this thing should have an simple solution.

I have currently this

```
var expressHandlebars = require('express-handlebars');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('hbs', expressHandlebars({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'main'}));
```

My folder structure is as follows

```
views

-- frontend
---- (doesn't matter, gulp takes care of this for FE).hbs

-- layouts
---- main.hbs

-- index.hbs
```

What I wanna archive is to have

```
views

-- frontend
---- (doesn't matter, gulp takes care of this for FE).hbs

-- backend
---- views
------ index.hbs
---- main.hbs
```

Basically, I want when I open my views folder in root to have frontend and then backend folder. Backend folder in root should have main layout and then in folders different partials for specific views.

I can add backend folder without issues which changing

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

to

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/backend');
```

**But how do I swap the that layout is in the root of the views folder?**

Just doing this will throw an error because he will look for layout in `/backend/layouts/main.hbs` and I want it to be in the root.

Also, later I render things by saying `res.render('index', data);`. Proposed solution should be able to do the same, or at least `res.render('views/index', data);` because the new views would be in folders.

Any help or tips appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, found it out with help of coworker.

There is an actual option for this which I managed to miss when looking over documentation.

```
app.engine('hbs', expressHandlebars({
                      extname: 'hbs', 
                      defaultLayout: 'main', 
                      layoutsDir: './views/backend'
                  }));
```